# react navigation - prop value being used as navigation setOption: paremeter key

Tags: javascript, react-native

Is it possible to the something as follows:

```
const MyComponent = (position) => {

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      position: () => <CustomComponent />
    });
  }, [navigation, position]);

...
};
```

So the `position` value being passed to MyComponent will either be: 'headerLeft' or 'headerRight'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `position` is a string containing `'headerLeft'` or `'headerRight'`, you could just create the object and pass it in:

```js
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  let opts = { };
  opts[position] = () => <CustomComponent />;

  navigation.setOptions(opts);
}, [ navigation, position ]);
```

Comment: Thanks. I get an error: left is not a function... left is an instance of an object (or right is not a function) depending on whether I pass 'headerLeft' or 'headerRight' as the value

Comment: Please see the edit, I'd forgotten the inline arrow function!